# No CoreStorage logical volume groups found

Tags: macos, hard-drive, mac, disk-utility

I ran the following command on my Mac

```
diskutil corestorage revert BE18BCE1-9DEA-494F-84F0-9EFC34AFB9AE
```

And now running

```
diskutil corestorage list
```

Produces

```
No CoreStorage logical volume groups found
```

When it previously returned a large list of all the devices.

This is my disk utility.

[image]

I would like to have my coreStorage back so I can resize volumes and then finally use bootcamp.

Answer (score 0):

Well, of course it won't return anything for
`diskutil corestorage list`
as you just removed the Core Storage.

Try
`diskutil list`
which will list non Core Storage volumes

Comment: How can I add it back to the core storage then?

Comment: Why don't you just ask what you are actually trying to achieve? Right now this looks like it's heading towards [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) territory. At the moment, you have no Core Storage to add anything *back to*.

Comment: Ye, sorry. The ultimate goal is to be able resize the volumes again. I think its fairly straight forward :)

Comment: Then that is the question you should have asked. Disk Utility will not let you resize volumes, with or without CoreStorage. See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/154964/resizing-or-expanding-a-corestorage-volume for how to do it in Terminal. Don't start before you have a complete backup.

Comment: Then I don't mean volumes, I just want to resize Macintosh partition. I don't really care about the names :p

Comment: @Tetsujin: OT, thanks for XY reference.